# How to slice Data frame with Pandas, and operate on each slice

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new into pandas and python in general and I want to **know your opinion about the best way** to create a new data frame using slices of an "original" data frame.

input (original df):

```
   date        author_id  time_spent   
0  2020-01-02          1         2.5
1  2020-01-02          2         0.5
2  2020-01-02          1         1.5

3  2020-01-01          1         2
4  2020-01-01          1         1
5  2020-01-01          3         3.5
6  2020-01-01          2         1.5
7  2020-01-01          2         1.5
```

expected output (new df):

```
   date        author_id  total_time_spent   
0  2020-01-01          1                 3
1  2020-01-01          2                 3
2  2020-01-01          3                 3.5

3  2020-01-02          1                 4
4  2020-01-02          2                 0.5
```

I want:

- Slice the original df by day.
- Operate each day to get the total_time_spent
- Create new df with these data

What you think which is the most efficient way?

Thanks for share your answer!

Answer (score 2):

What we will do

```
df = df.groupby(['date','author_id'])['time_spent'].sum().reset_index()

         date  author_id  time_spent
0  2020-01-01          1         3.0
1  2020-01-01          2         3.0
2  2020-01-01          3         3.5
3  2020-01-02          1         4.0
4  2020-01-02          2         0.5
```

Comment: Works! Looks pretty easy when you know and understand the library, but it's a different programming mindset for me. Thanks for your help @YOBEN_S